# C++ class type in function parameters

Tags: c++

Say I have two classes setup as shown below. Basically I want to pass the class1 object defined in main() to a method in the second class. When I try to compile this, it says that class1 has not been declared. Can anyone explain why this doesn't work and how I can fix it?

```
//class1.h:

class class1
{
public:
    class1();
    void method1();
private:
    int myNumber;
};

//class1.cpp has the implementation for method1();

//class2.h:

class class2
{
public:
    class2();
    void method2(class1 myclass);
};

//class2.cpp:

#include "class1.h"
#include "class2.h"

int main( void )
{
    class1 myclass;
    class2 anotherClass;

    anotherClass.method2(myclass);

    return 0;
}

void class2::method2(class1 myclass)
{
    return;
}
```

Answer (score 6):

You are missing the `class` keyword in your class definitions.

instead of `class1{...}` you need `class class1{...}`, etc.

Comment: whoops, missed those while typing it out. Still get the same error with the class keyword used.

Comment: the exact error message is: error: ‘class1’ has not been declared. The line number it gives is the method2() prototype in class2.

Comment: With the `include` order in the posted code, there should not be such an error...Hmm...

Answer (score 1):

In `class2.h`, the compiler does not "know" how `class1` is defined. There are two possible solutions:

- Add an `#include "class1.h"` in `class2.h`
- Add a so-called *forward declaration* of `class1` in `class2.h` by simply declaring `class class1;` at the top of the header. You then need to change your `method2` to either expect a *reference* or a *pointer* to `class1`. If you then add `#include "class1.h"` in `class2.cpp`, everything will work.

Answer (score 1):

the only clean solution is to include the header defining `class class1` before the definition of `class class2`.

Note that a forward declaration (al la Gnosophilon's answer) won't help here, as it only *declares* the class, but does not *define* it. This means that you can use a pointer or reference to the class, but not more, in particular you cannot pass `class1 myclass` by value as you try to do.